# How can I remove an automated link in my wordpress-theme?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

and first of all: thanks for your help!

I'am using a wordpress-theme called "waipoua" which looks nice but has it's flaws, which I would like to remove. One of them is a php-function, that automatically sets links to (a) every article I publish and (b) all comments related to this article. The following image shows what I mean: http://www.imagebanana.com/view/6xvi6y5n/ScreenshotStackOverflow.jpg (Sorry, I didn't have enough stackoverflow-reputation to embed the image in my post.)

The anchor-text of the first link is the date which says "26. Mai 2013", the anchor-text of the second link says "0 Kommentare". The first links to "url.com/postname", the second links to "url.com/postname#comments". At best I would like to display the information (date/ number of comments) but without a link.

In my content.php the code is the following:

```
    <aside class="entry-details">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="entry-date"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></a></li>
        <li class="entry-comments"><?php comments_popup_link( __( '0 comments', 'waipoua' ), __( '1 comment', 'waipoua' ), __( '% comments', 'waipoua' ), 'comments-link', __( 'comments off', 'waipoua' ) ); ?></li>
        <li class="entry-edit"><?php edit_post_link(__( 'Edit Post &rarr;', 'waipoua') ); ?></li>
    </ul>
</aside><!--end .entry-details -->
```

To remove the first link is fairly easy, I guess. I just need to remove the a-tag and everything related to it. But how do I remove the second link? I don't understand the specific code to find the answer myself.

Every help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the second link replace this line of PHP:

`<?php comments_popup_link( __( '0 comments', 'waipoua' ), __( '1 comment', 'waipoua' ), __( '% comments', 'waipoua' ), 'comments-link', __( 'comments off', 'waipoua' ) ); ?>`

with this one:

`<?php comments_number(); ?>`

To make this function display '0 comments' like your original code you can pass a parameter to it to specify whatever you'd like it to say when there are no comments.

`<?php comments_number( '0 comments' ); ?>`

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your answer. Anyways, thanks a lot! This finally helped. The only thing that's kind of confusing is the number displayed after I changed the content.php.

Before the changes it said "0 Kommentare" (engl. "0 Comments"). Now it just says "Keine Kommentare" (engl. "No Comments"). Is there any chance to make my theme display the number ("0") instead of the word ("Keine").

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to investigate the inner workings of the `comments_popup_link` function.

Have you tried removing `'comments-link',` from the array to see if that's what sets the link?

Comment: I already tried to delete every part of the "comments_popup_link" function, but nothing got rid of the link. Sometimes it didn't worked afterwards but the link was always there.